# Find matching string from two Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, compare, string-comparison

Array1

```
"ANGEL MARTIN ROMERO RIVERA"
"CRISOGONO CORTES ZARATE"
"RAFAEL ARMANDO DE LEON ALVARADO"
```

Array2

```
"ANGEL MARTIN"
"CRISOGONO ZARATE"
"RAFAEL DE LEON ALVARADO"
```

Can you please tell me how I can compare/match both arrays ???

Comment: Please [edit] your post to clarify what you expect and what you've tried.

Comment: I have added javascript solution but you need to create a custom comparer.  You want to match "ANGEL MARTIN ROMERO RIVERA" with "ANGEL MARTIN" so you have to do this manually.  So that it will not match "ANGEL MARTIN ROMERO RIVERA" with "ANGEL CARLOS MARTIN", thus my javascript solution is a step in the right direction...

Comment: Updated with C# example.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] array1 = new string[] { "ANGEL MARTIN ROMERO RIVERA", "CRISOGONO CORTES ZARATE", "RAFAEL ARMANDO DE LEON ALVARADO", "TEST" };
        static string[] array2 = new string[] { "ANGEL MARTIN", "CRISOGONO ZARATE", "RAFAEL DE LEON ALVARADO", "TEST" };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
            {

                for (var j = 0; j < array2.Length; j++)
                {

                    // compare (if they will equal)
                    if (array1[i] == array2[j])
                    {
                        // will match Array1 & Array2 on "TEST", ok, so loop...
                        Console.WriteLine("Match: {0}array1:{1}{2}array2:{3}", System.Environment.NewLine, array1[i], System.Environment.NewLine, array2[j]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // if data is like your example
                        if (array1[i].Contains(array2[j]))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Match: {0}array1:{1}{2}array2:{3}", System.Environment.NewLine, array1[i], System.Environment.NewLine, array2[j]);
                            // match on
                            // will match Array1 & Array2 on "ANGEL MARTIN" and "TEST", ok, so loop...
                            // will NOT match on CRISOGONO ZARATE, but the else condition will...
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // so, to get this match we do
                            var array2subArray = array2[j].Split(' ');

                            for (var k = 0; k < array2subArray.Length; k++)
                            {
                                // match all the terms in each array where the match is possible (or the smaller against the larger, i.e., if array1[i] is a name of 4 words and array2[j] is a name of 2 words, for this to be a valid match, both of the words in array2[j] must be contained in array1[i]
                                // I would write the code but then that would leave out the fun for you...

                                // Here's a start...
                                // you need to fix the below, but it is a start, blah, blah, blah...
                                if (array1[i].Contains(array2subArray[k]))
                                {
                                    // this will match on "CRISOGONO"
                                    Console.WriteLine("Potential Match: {0}array1:{1}{2}array2:{3}", System.Environment.NewLine, array1[i], System.Environment.NewLine, array2[j]);
                                    Console.WriteLine("processing furter to see if true match...");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 1 way how to do this, but you can try a plethora of other solutions too... here is a PURE VANILLA javascript solution

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It's really a low quality question, and sometimes I really doubt that whether we should answer these questions at all or not.

Comment: @mok WOW! I fixed it!

Answer (score -3):

In This Cases The Size Of Two Arrays Should Be Equal

This Code Maybe UseFul For You

```
public bool Compare(string[] arr1,string[] arr2)
{
   bool result=true;
   for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
   {
     if(arr1[i].ToLowwer()!=arr2[i].ToLowwer())
     {
       result=false;
       break;
     }
   }
   return true;
}
```